# Writing data to a text file column wise in C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I am a beginner in C++. I have input the values of the variables(belonging to a class) through an array of objects. Now how do I write them to the text file column wise as follows?? Thanks.........

```
SLNO    NAME      ADDRESS        PHONE NO     TYPE      
   1.   ABC       xyzagsgshsh    27438927     Mobile
   2.   QWE       qwhjbbdh       78982338     Landline
```

This is my code for storing the data. How do I make it into a text file with contents as below?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class emp
{
    string name,address,phone,type;
    public:
    void getdata();
}obj[5];

void emp::getdata()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter the details:";
    cout<<"\nName: ";cin>>name;
    cout<<"Address:";
    cin>>address;
    cout<<"Phone number: "; cin>>phone;
    cout<<"\nType of phone? (Landline/Mobile) :";
    cin>>type;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream ptr;
    ptr.open("Phone.dat",ios::out);
    cout<<"\nEnter the no.of.records: ";
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        obj[i].getdata();
        ptr.write((char*)&obj[i],sizeof(obj[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you've input these values then you've done the hard bit so I'm a bit puzzled why you're stuck on the output. Can you show the code you've written so far, or explain what it is that you're stuck on. Your question is a bit vague as it is.

Comment: Start by learning the formatted output capabilities of the standard library. You can find out all about them on [this website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), or lookup "C++ formatted output" on google.

Comment: @john: The code is as above. I need to make the Phone.dat file into a text file as mentioned.

Comment: @Razius Well you don't use `write`, which is for binary data, just `ptr << obj[i].name << '' obj[i].address << '\n';` etc. is a start. Use `ptr` just like you'd use `cout`. Since you already know how to use `cout` you already know how to write to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already created a filestream, you can take advantage of the output flags (std::left, std::right and std::setw):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/left/

Now, in order to ensure that any string stored in any object of the emp class doesn't exceed the size that you allocate to the ofstream/ostream through std::setw, you can use string::resize.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a string/[file](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) stream, newlines, and [std::setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/)

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "SLNO" << std::setw(10) << "NAME" << std::setw(10) << "ADDRESS" << std::setw(10) << "PHONE NO" << std::setw(10) << "TYPE\n";
```

this will space all the text with `10-text lenght` spaces and put it into `example.txt`

remember to check the file for validity and close the file.

Comment: Note that by default, `ostream` right justifies.  (This is generally what is wanted for numeric values.)  Because of this, it's often easier to use `resize` directly on the strings you're outputting.

Comment: but will the values I enter be stored to the text file under the right columns?

Comment: if you enter the amount of spaces (just make sure your column text is never going to be of greater lenght than setw(x), where x is the amount of total characters+spaces your column can have), yes.

Comment: for example if you have setw(10) before a column but the text you enter in it is 12 characters long, the whole line will be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  For simple output to a console
window (or if you have a fixed width font elsewhere, but that's
rather rare), you can use the `std::setw` before each element,
specifying the width of the field.  For text (`std::string`),
however, it's often easier to just use `resize`, and make it the
correct size to begin with.